# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, i got that in my crash report from play store, suggest me to how resolve that....

Tags: java, android, json, exception, android-volley

play store show that exception error occurred in crash report. please help me to resolve that. log and java code are following.In this i got youtube url from my created api but it may be be exception on dialog.dismis method

log report

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:412)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:338)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:509)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:492)
at com.sevakk.www.msg.Home$2.onResponse(Home.java:112)
at com.sevakk.www.msg.Home$2.onResponse(Home.java:104)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6838)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Java Code

```
 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

 InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
 String url = "http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx.php";
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
 private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
 private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

 List<Post_Data> list;

 private InterstitialAd interstitial;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(Home.this);
    // Insert the Ad Unit ID
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    list = new ArrayList<Post_Data>();

    getInfo();

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
}

private void getInfo() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
    dialog.setMessage("please wait...");
    dialog.show();
    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("server_response");
                dialog.dismiss();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Post_Data data = new Post_Data();
                    data.id = object1.getString("id");
                    data.url = object1.getString("url");
                    data.date = object1.getString("date");
                    data.postImageId = object1.getString("time");
                    data.text = object1.getString("desc");
                    data.eventdate = object1.getString("duration");
                    list.add(data);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter = new YoutTubeAdapter(Home.this, list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.e(">>>", "error is :" + error.toString());

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    int socketTimeout = 120000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    request.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    queue.add(request);
}

public void displayInterstitial() {
// If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is there on line no 112 ?

Comment: dialog.dismiss();   in getinfo() method

Comment: I only can think that you are trying to dismiss a dialog when the app is in background, or dialog already dismissed

Comment: this is not happn always...

Comment: it works fine but crash report...

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the below code on line 112.

```
 try {
      if (!Home.this.isDestroyed()) {

        if ((dialog != null) && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.e("Custom Tag", "Custom Message", e);
} catch ( Exception e) {
    Log.e("Custom Tag", "Custom Message", e);
} finally {
    dialog = null;
}
```

General idea is like, check whether your activity is destroyed, and if not destroyed, check whether your dialog is showing or not then dismiss your dialog.